# Progress bar keeps on loading though user cancels the operation and no ajax call is made

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have bounded a progress bar to a button which makes an ajax call. If the call is made, everything works fine. But if the user clicks on the button and cancels the operation, ajax call is not made but the progress bar is shown and it keeps on loading. How can i solve this issue. I have tried `ajaxStart()` and `beforeSend`, it doesn't seems to work.

The below pop up is shown, if user click on resend, it works. if cancel is clicked the above issue occurs[image].

Below is the code which is bounded to the button :

```
function ajaxcall(columnValue){
$.ajax({
    url: '/analyze/',
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data:{'project':$("#label2").attr("value"),'columnValue':columnValue},
    success: function(result) {
        stop();
        document.getElementById("stop").disabled=false;
        document.getElementById("start").disabled=false;

},  error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
       if(xhr.status==404 || xhr.status==401){window. location. reload()}
       else{
        document.getElementById("start").disabled=false;
        document.getElementById("progressbar").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("htmlreport").style.display="block";
         $('#view_report').html(xhr.responseText);}
      },
                beforeSend: function () {
                  start("Processing");
                },
});
}
```

In the above code  `start("Processing")` displays the progressbar. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Usually that popup is due to having gotten to the current page by having submitted a form in the previous page.

Comment: Yes. Here the problem is clicking on the button starts the progress bar though no ajax call is made. I want the progress bar to be displayed only if ajax call is made

Comment: How is your button set up?

Comment: button onclick will call ajaxcall(columnValue) function which is shown in the code above. start("Processing") within beforesend: function() will trigger the progress bar